# Iterate through 1 map or declare 2 maps

Tags: c++, stdmap

Given scenario:

~800 objects inside map with one of object properties (`int`) as key.

`FindObject` function to find object by that property (simple `return map[property_value]`), called very often in my program

`FindObjectByName` function to find object by another property, that iterates through map and compares `std::string` property, called often in my program

Is it better (more efficient) to create second map that holds the same object but `std::string` as a key or keep my `FindObjectByName` function? If so how could I measure it?

Edit:
I remove/add items frequently.

Comment: Do you add/remove items frequently ?

Comment: 800 entries isn't some number you should start to worry about performance-

Comment: @Jarod42 yes I do.

Comment: @Jarod42 I add/remove item each 10-15s but in stress situations it could be really frequent (few items each second)

Comment: If your architecture is as-described and you embark on trying to have a different map hole "the same objects" with different keys, you'll quickly find that isn't immediately automagic. The second map will hold *copies* of whatever is in the first map. Regardless, I concur with @πάνταῥεῖ. 800 objects is nothing. And a "few items each second" is anything-but-stressed in the real world. But if you really want to climb on this train, something like the [boost multiindex container library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) may be something of interest.

Comment: Have you profiled this to see if using `FindObjectByName` actually causes problems?

Comment: Would be the string the representation of the integer? If yes, then you can only use a map indexed by the string and when you need to search the integer you convert it to string

Comment: Use two maps, keyed by a `std::string` and an `int`, with the values of the maps being `std::shared_ptr` to the objects. A single instance for each object, referenced by both maps./